# scroll to <li> on click with overflow (javascript)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to scroll to an li element on click. Using just javascript. The issue is that, I have: `overflow:auto`. Hence the list is in a `ul` that has a scroll bar.

Method I have currently:

```
scrollToEnd() {
            var container = this.$el.querySelector("#test");
            container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
}
```

This method is called when I click to open a new user. (each user has messages, the messages are displayed in a ul, with li items).

My `li` items are generated when you click on a user. However nothing is happening, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `scrollToEnd` after some `messages` property assigned it will not work because DOM is not updated yet. You should do DOM manipulations in `nextTick` callback, see snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   messages: []
  },
  methods: {
      load() {
         // generate messages
         this.messages = Array.apply(null, Array(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))).map((_, i) => i)
         // ul is updated after tick
         this.$nextTick(() => {
            var container = this.$el.querySelector("#test");
            container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
         })
      }
  }
})
```

```css
#test {
  background: grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul id="test" style="display: block; height: 100px; overflow: auto">
    <li v-for="msg in messages">{{ msg }}</li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="load" >Load</button>
</div>
```